# How often does the Status Report expect Cron to run?

Tags: cron, system-status

I am on CiviCRM 5.33.1.  The system Status Report gives warnings like this, taken about 90 minutes later at 12:26.  Cron is deliberately set to run slowly since this is a development system.  How often does one need to run cron to avoid this message - or is there a bug somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expects it at least once an hour. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.33.0/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php#L317